# PHP Warning – yii\base\ErrorException Missing argument 2 for yii\db\Query::join(),

Tags: php, mysql, yii2

## PHP Warning – yii\base\ErrorException Missing argument 2 for yii\db\Query::join(),

what is the error in code? please help me

```
     $query = new Query; 
     $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
             'query'=> $query
                        ->select(['vchr_name','vchr_actual_hours','vchr_worked_hours','fk_int_payroll_month','fk_int_payroll_year'])
                        ->from('tbl_payroll')
                         ->join(['INNER JOIN','tbl_employee', 'TblEmployee.pk_int_emp_id=TblPayroll.fk_int_emp_id'])
                        ->where(['pk_int_payroll_id'=> $id])
                        ->One(),       

         ]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the documentation at http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-query.html#join()-detail there should be 4 parameters of join(). In your case it should be 
    `->join('INNER JOIN','tbl_employee', 'TblEmployee.pk_int_emp_id=TblPayroll.fk_int_emp_id', [])` or you can omit the last 4th non mandatory parameter.

Comment: how can i join 3 tables

Comment: just use one more ->join after the one you have